# Clearing the assigned user using mass update in sugar crm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Our admin user has asked if it's possible to clear the assigned user of a accounts using the mass update functionality. At the moment, if he leaves this field blank the user is not cleared out from the affected records. But if I wanted to provide him with the "X" button to deliberately clear out the selection (as you get on the normal edit screen) I suppose I'd be looking at a code modification? Has anybody done something like this before and knows where I would need to make the change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: am i asking a wrong question ?

Comment: Just to be curious: why you need to remove/erase one of the most extremelly important record attribute in SugarCRM logic?

Comment: this is the client requirement bro

Comment: What do you think of assigning needed records to a fake user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, so maybe an alternative is in order, as follows.

Create a use called 'unassigned'.
Allocate all the records to this user via mass update
Deactivate the user (optionally)

This will explain to anyone that they are unassigned, and allow you search for these.

With commercial versions of Sugar there may be licence issues with an extra user. Deactivating them will mean you don't have to pay for a non-existent user.

I hope this helps,
Greg Ambrose